sifted diagram of localizations
Let $C$ be a stable $\infty$-category and let $C_i$ be a sifted diagram of subcategories such that there are commuting localizations $L_i:C\to C_i$. Consider the intersection $C_\infty:=\cap_{i\in I} C_i$. Is the corresponding localization given by $X\to \mathrm{colim}\,L_i(X)$? Feel free to put any additional assumptions if that helps. I think I see this for $I$ filtered. I am particularly interested in the case where each $C_i$ is the category of complete modules over an analytic ring (see 4.1.1 of https://blogs.cuit.columbia.edu/jr4460/files/2024/09/SeminarSolidGeometrynotes2-1.pdf for the definition of an analytic ring). It seems to me that in case where $B$ is a colimit of a sifted diagram of analytic rings $A_i$ then the corresponding completion functor $-\otimes_{B^\triangleright}B$ is simply given by $ \mathrm{colim}(-\otimes_{A_i^\triangleright}A_i)$. I am failing to see why $ \mathrm{colim}(-\otimes_{A_i^\triangleright}A_i)$ is $B-$complete. Intuitively this should be true: for a family of (say discrete) rings $R_i$ and a family $M_i$ where each $M_i$ is a $R_i$ module the colimit $M_i$ is naturally a module over $ \mathrm{colim}\,R_i$ (provided the indexing diagram is sifted).

Just for clarification: with "localization", you mean that each $C_i$ is a full subcategory of $C$, and that $L_i$ has a fully faithful right adjoint?

@DaniëlApol yes, this is what I had in mind, thank you for your answer and comment!

Here is a solution assuming that you mean that each functor $L_i\colon C\to C_i$ is a left Bousfield localization, i.e. $L_i$ admits a fully faithful right adjoint. This makes that we can define $C_\infty=\bigcap_{i\in I} C_i$ as the full subcategory of $C$ on objects that are $L_i$-local for all $i\in I$. We will not need the assumption that $C$ is a stable $\infty$-category in this situation: we may take it to be an arbitrary $\infty$-category admitting colimits of the shapes that we need.
(Edit: you can ignore the next paragraph, and can replace afterwards every occurence of $I^\triangleleft$ with just $I$. Since $I$ is weakly contractible, the inclusion $I\to I^\triangleleft$ is cofinal, so my considerations below are not needed.)
Write $I^\triangleleft$ for the $\infty$-category obtained from $I$ by freely adjoining an initial object $\bot$. Assuming that $I$ is sifted, so is $I^\triangleleft$, as follows from the slice-category criterion for cofinality. We can extend the assignment $I\to\mathrm{Cat}_{\infty,C/}, i\mapsto L_i$ to a functor with domain $I^\triangleleft$ by declaring $L_\bot=\mathrm{id}_C$. This is still a left Bousfield localization. Note that $C_\infty=\bigcap_{i\in I^\triangleleft} C_i$ as well.
The reason we introduce this new diagram $\infty$-category is that the correct definition for $L_\infty$ is
$$
L_\infty x :=\mathrm{colim}_{i\in I^\triangleleft} L_i x
$$
The inclusion $I\to I^\triangleleft$ is generally not cofinal (Edit: but it is in our case, since $I$ is assumed to be sifted), so this detail matters (Edit: not really). We have now defined $L_\infty$ as a functor $C\to C$. To show that it corestricts to a left Bousfield localization $C\to C_\infty$, we show a couple of things:

The units $\eta_i\colon\mathrm{id}\Rightarrow L_i\colon C\to C$ induce via a colimit a natural transformation $\eta_\infty\colon\mathrm{id}\Rightarrow L_\infty\colon C\to C$.
$L_\infty\colon C\to C$ is idempotent as witnessed by $\eta_\infty$.
If $x\in C$ satisfies that $\eta_\infty\colon x\to L_\infty x$ is an equivalence, then $x$ is $L_i$-local for all $i\in I^\triangleleft$ (so $x\in C_\infty$). In particular, $L_\infty x\in C_\infty$ for any $x\in C$.
$\eta_\infty$ witnesses for every $x\in C$ and $y\in C_\infty$ an equivalence $C_\infty(L_\infty x,y)\simeq C(x,y)$. In other words, $L_\infty\colon C\to C_\infty$ is a left Bousfield localization.

Now for the proofs of these statements:

The compatability of all functors $L_i$ gives us an $I^\triangleleft$-shaped diagram $i\mapsto \eta_i$ in the arrow category $\mathrm{Fun}([1],C)$, which when restricted to the domains of all $\eta_i$ is a constant diagram on $\mathrm{id}_C$. Since $I^\triangleleft$ is weakly contractible (as is any sifted $\infty$-category), $I^\triangleleft$-shaped colimits of constant diagrams return the object on which the diagram was constant, so $\mathrm{colim}_{i\in I^\triangleleft}\eta_i=:\eta_\infty$ is a natural transformation $\mathrm{id}_C\to L_\infty$.
We use that each $L_i\colon C\to C$ is idempotent via its unit and that $I^\triangleleft\to I^\triangleleft\times I^\triangleleft$ is cofinal to see that, for any $x\in C$, we have
$$
L_\infty x\simeq \mathrm{colim}_{i\in I^\triangleleft} L_i x\simeq\mathrm{colim}_{i\in I^\triangleleft}L_iL_i x\simeq \mathrm{colim}_{j,i\in I^\triangleleft}L_j L_i x\simeq L_\infty L_\infty x.
$$
A bit of unwinding tells you that the composite equivalence is given by both $L_\infty\eta_\infty$ and $\eta_\infty L_\infty$.
For an $x$ such that $\eta_\infty\colon x\to L_\infty x$ is an equivalence, it suffices (in order to show that $x$ is $L_i$-local) to produce a map $\varphi_i\colon L_i x \to x$ such that the composite $\varphi_i\eta_i\colon x\to L_i x\to x$ is the identity. We define $\varphi_i$ as the composite of the canonical map $L_i x\to L_\infty x$ with $\eta_\infty^{-1}\colon L_\infty x\to x$. It is now immediate that $\varphi_i\eta_i$ is the identity on $x$. The combination of this result and statement 2. shows that $L_\infty x\in C_\infty$ for each $x\in C$.
Using that $y$ is $L_i$-local for all $i$, we compute
$$
C_\infty(L_\infty x,y)\simeq C(L_\infty x,y)\simeq\mathrm{lim}_{i\in I^\triangleleft}C(L_i x, y)\simeq\mathrm{lim}_{i\in I^\triangleleft} C(x,y)\simeq C(x,y),
$$
where the last equivalence follows once more from the fact that $I^\triangleleft$ is weakly contractible, so that limits of constant diagrams are given by the object on which the diagram is constant. One may check that the composite equivalence $C_\infty(L_\infty x,y)\simeq C(x,y)$ is given by precomposition with $\eta_\infty$.


thank you for a clean answer, considering  $I^\triangleleft$ instead of $I$ is one of the ideas I was missing!

@Semcio I made a mistake: since $I$ is weakly contractible (since it's sifted) actually $I\to I^\triangleleft$ is cofinal, so you can replace all instances of $I^\triangleleft$ with just $I$ and get the same functor $L_\infty$ and all the same results. The old proof still works, but it's just unnecessary extra work to talk about $I^\triangleleft$ instead of only $I$.
